# Power Automate to generate a reply to email from SharePoint

Tags: email, button, sharepoint, power-automate, eml

I have a SharePoint folder which contains files in .eml format.  These email files need to be replied to and currently users need to preview/download the file and then they can respond.  I am looking for a solution to use Power Automate to generate a 'Reply to email (V3)' action to function directly from the SharePoint folder.  I have created a column in the SharePoint library with a button to trigger the flow.  I am now trying to create a flow that will get the selected file and then automatically open a response to the email.  I am struggling as the file is saved in .eml format (it can be changed to .msg but when a file was downloaded it wouldn't open as an email) and the message ID and body cannot be extracted.  I have tried converting the file using 'base64ToString' function but this does not appear to be working.  If it is not possible to generate a Reply to email could I at least get the flow to download the file.  One other thing I've noticed is when the button is pressed to run the flow I need to confirm this in a panel appearing on the right, does this need to happen every time as I am trying to reduce the number of clicks to work the email.

Comment: Out of interest, what is the reason you want to have a trigger based on a SharePoint folder? Wouldn't a flow which triggers on the original mailbox be a lot easier to setup? Could you explain a bit more what the use case is behind this?

Comment: My department have desired to fix the archiving issues we have with users on Outlook. Therefore we have moved to a concept of automating the files directly into SharePoint via Power Automate, which I have built and it is working correctly.  Allowing metatagging to the files for sorting.  The issue was the EML files cannot be worked on the browser they must be downloaded.  I believe I have managed to sort out the best option using a Text Input in the flow trigger.  Once I have it properly completed I will update with my solution.

Comment: Have you made it? If I understand correctly, this seems unlikely to be possible as far as I know.